# Black screen with EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID flag in GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, egl

I'm configuring a GLSurfaceView to use the **EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID**. 
But within the render loop I get in the LogCat a **EGL_BAD_ALLOC**, and of course the screen is black.

My first assumption was that probably the test GPU (**Adreno 220**) is not supporting such flag, but egl reports that the configuration is supported.
The problem does not happen so far with any other tested GPU model.

**Method to get/test the EGLConfig:**

```
public EGLConfig chooseConfig(final EGL10 egl, final EGLDisplay display)
{
    // OpenGL ES 2 bit. EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT
    final int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 0x0004;

    // Extension for surface record
    final int EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID = 0x3142;

    final int[] attribList = { EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8, //
            EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8, //
            EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8, //
            EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8, //
            EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, //
            EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1, //
            EGL10.EGL_NONE };

    final EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
    final int[] numberConfigs = new int[1];

    if (egl.eglChooseConfig(display, attribList, configs, configs.length, numberConfigs) == false)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return configs[0];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure offhand why it's failing, but I'm also not sure why you're trying to do this. The EGL context in the GLSurfaceView is only used for rendering to the screen. Attempting to detach and and reattach it to the input Surface of a MediaCodec or MediaRecorder is a bad idea, as GLSurfaceView actively manages its context. If you want to record GL rendering, see the various examples in Grafika or http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#BreakoutPatch

Comment: No I don't attach/detach the GLSurfaceview. The input surface generated by MediaCodec is used with eglCreateWindowSurface to create an off-screen rendering surface, which requires a matching EGLConfig to the GLSurfaceView one, otherwise would fail because surfaces need to have the same EGL configuration. The issue is that only with the Adreno 220 setting the flag EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID to the EGLConfig fails with a EGL_BAD_ALLOC, once rendering has started.

Comment: Please see the Breakout patch, or "show + capture camera" activity in Grafika. These both use shared contexts and do not do anything elaborate in their GLSurfaceView EGL setup.